# Apache, Accessing files as a directory, Bug?

Tags: apache-2.2, bug

I found a problem with my Apache webserver:

Suppose I ONLY HAVE ONE file on my website (index.php):

example.com/index.php

When I access the URL using this way:

example.com/index.php/abc
or 
example.com/index.php/123

Apache will display the content of:
example.com/index.php

It has created a lot of problem to my web application. How can I make this as a 404 error?

Notice that my Apache is standard/default. I didn't do any modification to my Apache settings. OS is Fedora Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like you may have forgotten to configure something and are encountering intended behavior, but a bug. Not familiar enough with Apache to know what though.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know which Apache settings I should look into?

Comment: Can you clarify what behavior you're expecting?  What should Apache serve, if not index.php?

Answer (score 3):

this is the correct behavior indeed, as whatever comes after your page will be in PATH_INFO cgi variable used by server side scripting often.

Comment: Thanks. I notice that I can get the "real file path" from $_SERVER variables in PHP. However, it will be a lot of works to redirect all these "bad requests" to good requests using PHP. That's why I like to solve the problem on the Apache side, rather than PHP side.